# Excel - highlight the highest values in a column if there is more than one highest value when rounded

Tags: excel, formatting

Let's say I have a table like this:

[image]

where the 4 in b2 is actually 4.00001, and i want to highlight the highest/lowest values of the rounded values.

Using [this](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/questions/cond_format3_2010.php) only got me only the top value b2, which makes sense.

[image]

How would i do this so it highlights both b2 and b3 like this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the B1 cell, from the New formatting rule menu (as described in the tutorial you linked) you have to choose "Use a formula to dtermine which cells to format".
Then use the following formula:

```
=ROUND($B1,0)=ROUND(MAX($B:$B),0)
```

now you have to copy the B1 and past her format to the whole column B.